# How can I optimize the construction of a pair in this case?

Tags: c++

I have a

```
template<class Key, class Value, class Comp = std::less<Key> > class MyContainer;
```

which is implemented with a tree of nodes internally, where each node type is defined as below:

```
typedef std::pair<Key, Value> Node;
```

To erase one element from the container I need to provide the following method to the user:

```
void MyContainer::erase(const Key& k) {
   const Node n(k, default_value); // default_value is a data member, copied from Value() by default in the constructor of MyContainer
   //...
   mytree->remove(n); // search and remove the Node in case
}
```

The tree uses (a wrapper class derived from) `less<Key>` to compare and sort the elements in the tree.

As you might understand, the `remove()` method in the tree does not really need to access the second element of the pair to find the node. For this reason I would like to avoid the overhead of the copy of `default_value` to the second element of the `pair`.

Is there a way to get rid of this unnecessary overhead?

Edit: The type of the tree is given as

```
template<class T, class Comp = std::less<T> > class Tree;
```

Comment: Why can't you add a `remove` method that takes a `const Key&`? What type is `mytree`?

Comment: @David MyContainer is (a sort of) HashMap where each bucket is a tree

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `defualt_value` as some sort of place holder for `accept anything`? (like prolog)

If so I would change it so that you search for the key in the container then remove the element(s) that. (This could be an overload for `remove` or just a find followed by an explicit node removal.

You trying to repurpose your pair based remove function sounds like an overly complex design.

```
void MyContainer::erase(const Key& k) {
   const Node n(k, default_value);
   auto n=mytree->find(k);
   mytree->remove_node(*n); //or whatever you syntax is
}
```

I assume because you are using templates and good style that you are familiar with the `std::map`, `std::multimap` and there unordered equivelants.

Comment: MyContainer is (a sort of) HashMap where each bucket is a tree

Comment: Ah ok, out of interest would this not be better. `std::unordered_map<KeyType1, std::map<KeyType2, ValueType> >`, reimplementing the wheel is generally something to be avoided (note that if your don't have C++11 yet you can use the boost unordered map it is very similar

Comment: As an example, I have GCC4.7 and really don't like how unordered_map is implemented there. That hashmap implementation consumes too much memory for my needs. Even clear() does not reasonably make the map  use the empty buckets to store new elements. I think that behind an HashMap there are so many implementation details that sometimes it's worth reimplementing something specific for your requirements.

Comment: @Martin: unless this hash map has become a bottleneck in some sort of real time application, I personally would use of standard containers over an implementation which may be technically superior but functionally identical in almost all cases. The unordered containers are new and will have rough edges, over time (probably not that much) they will become better. For example I think clang are taking a very fresh approach to the std library when it get more mature concerning C++11 you can switch to that: that is just an opinion though.